# Fused location provider returns same location always

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have been trying to get my current location updates and used Fused location provider as suggested by Google but I am unable to get any update. I have searched thoroughly on web but couldn't find any solution. The location returned by fused provider is not even close to where I am, it shows some other country. Can anyone help me out here?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener ,
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mLocationTextView;

    private static final int LOC_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createLocationRequest();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        mLocationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    }

    private boolean isLocationProviderAvailable(){
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) || lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    private void requestLocation() {
        if (!hasLocationPermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOC_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }else {

            if(!isLocationProviderAvailable()){
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("No location service")
                        .setMessage("Location adapters are turned off. Please turn on and try again.")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.location_icon)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
                dialog.show();
            }else {
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean hasLocationPermission(){
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void createLocationRequest(){
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 5);
        mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(2);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == LOC_PERMISSION_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestLocation();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        log("onConnectionFailed -> %s", connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    private void log(String format, Object... args){
        Log.d("MainActivity", String.format(format, args));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        log("onLocationChanged()");
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        log("updateUI()");
        if(null != mCurrentLocation) {
            mLocationTextView.setText(String.format("Lat: %s, Lon: %s", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        requestLocation();
        log("onConnected()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        log("onConnectionSuspended()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce Interval and Fastest Interval and check.

Comment: Tried. No luck. It always return 33.xxxx, 33.xxxx

Comment: Why you used setNumUpdates?

Comment: That's just for testing. It returns same without setNumUpdates.

Comment: Have you check on device or emulator ?

Comment: I am checking on real device (Nexus 5)

Comment: Then how is it possible to change location frequently?

Comment: I don't want to change it. The location it returns does not reflect my current location.

Comment: DO you have a mock location provider on?

Comment: Do I need mock location provider on real device? I don't think so.

Comment: What is your current location shown on Google Map application and Try to press current location icon on map then try to check you code again and let me know what happen.

Comment: You have a typo, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Lat: %s, Lon: %s", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude())
```

The second parameter should be getLongitude, not getLatitude

Comment: Hah, I got it first.